# Translate $\neg p \lor (p \land q)$ to English

Tags: propositional-calculus

I started to learn discrete mathematics using "Discrete mathematics and its Application" book. In this book exercises I couldn't find answer to the below question.

> Let
>
> - $p$: I bought a lottery ticket this week.
> - $q$: I won the million dollar jackpot on Friday.
>
> Translate $$\neg p \lor (p \land q)$$ to English.

Comment: "**either** (I **do not** bought a lottery ticket this week) **or** (I bought a lottery ticket this week **and** I won the million dollar jackpot on friday)"

Comment: agree with that @MauroALLEGRANZA said with the caveat that "either FOO or BAR" can be both FOO and BAR in general.

Comment: I get the point thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us do it in steps.

First, we just replace the symbols by their 'word' analogues.

> NOT 'I bought a lottery ticket this week' OR ('I bought a lottery ticket this week' AND 'I won the million dollar jackpot on Friday.')

Second, let us smooth the sentence.

> I did not buy a lottery ticket this week, or I bought a lottery ticket this week and I won the million dollar jackpot on Friday.

Third, let us think about what the sentence means.

There are two options 'I did not buy' or 'I did buy'; in the second case 'I won.' This means *if* I did buy, *then* I did win. So:

> If I bought a lottery ticket this week, then I won the million dollar jackpot on Friday

Generally $\neg p \lor (p \land q)$ expresses "If *p*, then *q*."

Answer (score 2):

Direct translation:

Either I did not buy a lottery ticket this week, or I bought a lottery ticket this week and I won the million dollar jackpot on Friday.

You can simplify this by relying on the logical equivalence of $\color\red{\neg{x}\vee{y}}$ and $\color\green{{x}\implies{y}}$.

Thus $\color\red{\neg{p}\vee({p}\wedge{q})}$ is equivalent to $\color\green{{p}\implies{p}\wedge{q}}$, which is quivalent to ${p}\implies{q}$.

Hence your statement can be translated to:

If I bought a lottery ticket this week, then I won the million dollar jackpot on Friday.

Comment: I can understand but I wanted to do it without using laws